# Get datetime field value from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to get a datetime value from MySQL table. I stored it like `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'`, but when I want to get it to print in a page, I get this `'2019-04-01 00:00:00'` or only `'2019-04-01'`. If I check the database, I can see the time stored properly, but when I want to print it, I only get zeros.

```
if( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( '
    SELECT
        estadistica_id, 
        aprobados, 
        suspendidos, 
        pendientes, 
        envios, 
        fecha, 
        curso.curso_id, 
        identificador_envio, 
        curso.titulo AS titulo_curso
    FROM estadistica
    LEFT JOIN curso ON estadistica.curso_id = curso.curso_id
    ORDER BY titulo_curso ASC' . $order_by
) ) {
    if( true === $stmt->execute() ) {
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( 
            $estadistica_id, 
            $aprobados, 
            $suspendidos, 
            $pendientes, 
            $envios, 
            $fecha, 
            $curso_id, 
            $identificador_envio, 
            $titulo_curso 
        );
        if( ( $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows ) > 0 ) {
            while( $stmt->fetch() ) {
                echo $fecha;
            }
        }
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
```

$fecha prints `'2019-04-01'` and nothing more. I don't know how to print the date and time stored in the database.

Here goes the screenshots of the database, where you can see that the date and time is stored correctly.

[image: database1]
[image: database2]

I'm lost :(

Appreciate all your help ;)

Comment: What is the column type in the database?  If its a string, your code should work perfectly.  If its a defined as a timestamp, you may need to use a date formatting function to get it in the format you want.

Comment: R. Smith, the column type in the database was 'datetime'. Now I've changed it to 'varchar', as @GMB said, and it works perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When fetching a `datetime` value from database, the default format depends on your client. Most clients use MySQL default format (`'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`), but it looks like yours doesn't.

One solution would be to turn the date to a string with the expected format within the SQL query, using [MySQL function `DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

Consider:

```
SELECT
    estadistica_id, 
    ..., 
    DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'),
    ...
FROM estadistica
...
```

Comment: That's the solution for me. I converted the column type from 'datetime' to 'varchar' and applied DATE_FORMAT(). Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As R.Smith said in his comment, it should work if your column's format is `varchar`. You must have another one.

You can use `DateTime` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Example :

```php
$date = new \DateTime($fecha);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// => 2019-04-01 18:42:03
```

Comment: I've tried this solution, and it also works! As long as I convert the column type from 'datetime' to 'varchar'. Thank you!